# Oracle DB limiting access to first IP making a connection

Tags: oracle, connection

below the situation :

2 front-end that connects to the same database.

the 2 applications cannot run at the same time or it will corrupt the DB.

I see how we can manage it from the application point of view but want to add DB security.

Question :

What are the best practice form an oracle point of view ?

Is it possible to have a check on the connection source IP, first IP that open a connection get exclusivity and can open further sessions ?

a flag could make sense but if the application crash we need to reset the flag.

Many thanks in advance for the ideas and advices !

Comment: "Best Practice" would be to write your application in a way that it does not corrupt the DB.

Comment: Yeah thanks.. As mentioned, it's from db point of view without trusting the application.

Comment: By default Oracle is a multi-user capable RDBMS. How would you "manage" to corrupt the database?